# On iPad, is there a way to go to "end of list" or "end of page" -- besides going to "top of page"?

Tags: ipad, ui

There is a way on iPad to go to top of the page or list, in email's list of emails, or in iBooks's highlighting and notes, for example, by tapping on the top status bar of the iPad screen.

But is there a way to go to the end of page or list?  For example, on iBooks, when the highlightings and notes are shown, sometimes a user may want to see the last highlighting or notes, but in some cases, the list is 12 pages long.  In this case, is there a quick way to go to the end, or will a user just need to scroll the 12 pages to reach the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to scroll to the end of a document other than by swiping repeatedly. It would be nice if Apple could add a specific gesture for this common action. If enough people request this feature at http://www.apple.com/feedback/ipad.html maybe they will add it into a future version of iOS.

Comment: That would be a much more difficult feature to implement, I imagine, since iOS apps share a common top element used to activate "go to top"  (the status bar), but they share no such common bottom element. Meanwhile, it's worth pointing out that the more rapidly you swipe in a scrolling view, the more quickly it will scroll to the bottom. So there's that, at least. :)

Comment: Or it can be: tap the left side of status bar to mean top of list, and right side of the status bar to mean bottom of list.

Comment: Another idea could be a two-finger double-tap near the bottom of the screen. Or a one-finger tap-and-hold near the bottom of the screen where there is no text.

Answer (score -2):

HOW TO GO TO THE END OF YOUR DOCUMENT FAST WITHOUT SCROLLING THE SCREEN ON YOUR iPAD WITH YOUR FINGERS TEDIOUSLY
When you want to stop typing press two spacing to put in the period or full-stop sign (.), automatically。Then press two or more spacing again and type in another period or full-stop sign (.). You may also use other punctuation marks as you prefer.
Now touch the screen of your iPad.  A panel will appear like this:
Select   Select all   Paste   insert
Move the cursor to the second period sign and select it.
Next touch the iPad screen again.  The following will appear:
Cut   Copy   Paste   Delete   Define   New comment
Choose and touch the last one ie.  New comment 
On the right-hand side bar/space your name will appear or you type in something like The end.
Now close the document by touching the save arrow on top of the left-hand corner.
When next you open your document press REVIEW on top of the screen panel.   After activating REVIEW look for the arrow pointing to the left just below the word HOME on your iPad.  Press this arrow.  Your document will rush to the end of it.  No need to tire your fingers scrolling down tens or hundreds of pages!  Be careful when you continue your typing of your document.  YOU MUST PUT THE CURSOR BETWEEN THE TWO PERIODS AT THE END OF YOUR DOCUMENT. What happens if you put the cursor after the second period sign?   You find out……….. Happy iPading.

Comment: This seems to apply to a specific app only

Comment: Nowadays i never swipe with my fingers anymore to get to the end of my document.  after setting, i just press REVIEW and click next comment.  it just jumps to the end my 59 pages of diary.

Comment: Where exactly (in which app) do you press REVIEW?